# JDK Version inconsistent

Tags: java

My os is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
$ cat /etc/profile   # part content of this file
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH

$ echo $JAVA_HOME  
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_101

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

$ ls /usr/local/java/
jdk1.7.0_79/  jdk1.8.0_101/
```

Why is my java version still jdk7?

Comment: Try `echo $PATH` and you will see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu has ability to work with multiple java versions. In your case, it just means that it has both JDK 7 and JDK 8 installed in your system but is using JDK 7.

To switch from one java version to another, you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config java`. This will list all JDKs installed in your system, just enter the number corresponding to JDK 8 and it should switch to JDK 8.

Comment: I think the OP is using a customized java installation. Note his JAVA_HOME is in /usr/local

Answer (score 1):

Run `which java` in your command shell.  That will tell you where the `java` command you are running is coming from.

I suspect that is will tell you "/usr/bin/java" ... because this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

puts your new bin directories onto the end of the search path, not the beginning.

However, the better way to do this would be to use `alternatives` as suggested by another Answer.  (With a custom installation in "/usr/local" this will require some fiddling around to get "alternatives" to understand the alternative.)